# Store MVC3 authentication data across sessions in iPad web-app mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ipad, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have a MVC3 project for running on the iPad in the web-app mode. I use FormsAuthentication to realize a login/logout functionality which calls `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, true)` to store the login information into a cookie. In all major browser including the safari mobile the cookie is saved persistend, across sessions. Only in the web-app mode the cookie is sometimes cleared during browsing the web-app and it is definitely deleted after closing the web-app. Is there any possibility to save the login information across session in web-app mode, too?

I know that the HTML5 local storage feature could be used, but I've no idea how to implement `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, true)` manually by using the new local storage. And besides that, I'm not sure whether the local storage is safe enough to store such critical data.

Comment: this is an iPad (iPhone too?) feature for running websites in fullscreen mode so that the website has the look and feel of a native app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer after a lot of research: You have to force the usage of cookies in the authentication node of web.config through **cookieless="UseCookies"**:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```